# Puma issue preventing from running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATED: Per Michael's suggestion/comment, I am reformatting below display code. I also made the minor fixes on code like `rails` which was commented out and also not latest. The history of the Gemfile dates back to Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial - I had made an app using it but not touched in last 2 years.

Now I have run `bundle update` which resulted in a lot of things getting updated which was nice. However at the end it gave me the same error as before - see below pls. Any further advice would be great pls. Thank you.

```
Installing puma 3.12.6 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
....
An error occurred while installing puma (3.12.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.12.6' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Pls see below my Gemfile.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.6.3"

gem 'rails',          '5.0.7.2'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'faker',          '1.6.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.5.1'
gem 'fog',                     '1.38.0'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.11'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.4'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.5'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 4.3.3'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'figaro',       '1.1.1'
gem 'haml'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'city-state'
gem 'redis'
gem 'devise', '>= 4.2.0'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'geoip'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'trix'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.1.0.pre3'
gem 'arctic_admin'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'money'
gem 'eu_central_bank'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'cloudinary'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.20.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile here? or run `gem list puma`

Comment: Post your Gemfile and full stack trace please?

Comment: I posted it in main - thank you folks

Comment: ubuntu:~/environment/oursurplus (master) $ gem list puma

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

puma (2.9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Gemfile (note correct spelling—not GemFile), it appears that the version of Puma is wrong. If you’re using a Gemfile.lock with a different version, that could account for the error. Also, your `rails` gem appears to be commented out, which is unlikely to be right.

One step you’re likely to need is this:

```
bundle update
```

That being said, the version mismatch indicates that there may be deeper issues. Where did this Gemfile come from? Why is `rails` commented out? Etc. These are the sort of things that would help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of Michael Hartl on twitter.

Had to remove Gemfile.lock and hardcode puma version to gem `'puma', '~> 4.1'` and then run bundle install.

If my website ever gets its 15mins of fame, I will be talking about `Michael` for the first 5 mins at least.